# Conjugate subgroups and conjugate elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

While trying to prove that the alternating group $A_5$ is a simple group, I came across two assertions I see as contradicting, that is :

- the 5-cycles are not all conjugate to each other

(proven here : [Show that not all 5 cycles in $A_5$ are conjugate in $A_5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464582/show-that-not-all-5-cycles-in-a-5-are-conjugate-in-a-5))

- if $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are 5-cyles, then by one of the Sylow theorems, $<\sigma>$, which is a 5-Sylow is conjuguate to $<\sigma'>$, another 5-Sylow

Can anyone demystify this ?

Answer (score 4):

Two cyclic groups are conjugate if each generator of one is conjugate to *a* generator of the other.

This does not mean that *every* generator of one is conjugate to *every* generator of the other.

In particular if $A=\langle a\rangle$ and $B=\langle b\rangle$ then $a\sim b^n$ and $b\sim a^m$ for some $n,m$ relatively prime to the orders of $a$ and $b$ (so that $b^n$ and $a^m$ are also generators of $B$ and $A$ respectively), but from this we cannot deduce that $a\sim b$, or in other words we still don't know if $a,b$ are *themselves* conjugate.

Answer (score 0):

More specific to the alternating groups, when single conjugacy classes in $S_n$ split into two classes in $A_n$, we have $a\not\sim a^{-1}$, however $\langle a\rangle=\langle a^{-1}\rangle$ is always true.